# Dynamic allocation of char**

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is the text of my example:

> Loading number N then N words from standard input. The word is not longer than 100 characters. Dynamically allocate array of loaded words as a series of pointers to character strings (dynamic array needs to have a type `char **`). Provide a set of words printed in a single line with spaces between the words.

Can someone tell me how to set the character limits?

Should I do this:

```
scanf("%100s", str[i])
```

or something else?
BTW, how can I allocate the memory for a type like this (`char **`,`int **`,etc)?

This is my code that I've done, so what have I done wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("How much words? "), scanf("%d", &n);
    char *str= (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        str[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
        printf("%d. word: ", i + 1),scanf("%s", str[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", str[i]);
    }
    getch();
```

Comment: `malloc()` is useful for allocating memory - search on keyword "malloc".  Use `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux
I've used it but I'm not sure if I've done it correct,I've posted me code so you can check it if you want.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what should I change in str[i]?
You've written the same code twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong type for array of pointers

```
// char *str
char **str
```

Code clean-up with comments.

```
// add void
int main(void) {
    int i,n;
    // Easier to understand if on 2 lines-of code
    printf("How much words? ");
    // test scanf() results
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) return -1;

    // Consider different style to allocate memory, as well as type change
    //  char *str= (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    char **str= malloc(sizeof *str * n);
    // check allocation
    assert(str == NULL); 

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str[i] = malloc(sizeof *str[i] * 100);
        // check allocation
        assert(str[i] == NULL); 

        printf("%d. word: ", i + 1);
        fflush(stdout);

        // limit input width to 99
        // test scanf() results
        if (scanf("%99s", str[i]) != 1) return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Add () to clearly show beginning/end of string 
        printf("(%s) ", str[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I can't use void in the main function and also I can't use assert.

Comment: `int main(void)` is allowed by standard C as well as `assert()`.  If there are limitations to the post, best to list them all there rather than detail them out a few at a time in the comments.  IAC, I am sure you can adjust this answer as needed with your additional limitations.

Comment: We haven't learned to implement the void function like in your code.
Also now I hear for the  assert function  for the 1st time.
Is there other way besides using assert?

Sorry, I'm a beginner on this forum and don't know well how to post a good question.

Comment: Its OK to to learn about new things like `main(void)` in SO.  Seeing it here, you now have learned how to implement it.  Read about `assert()` or Instead of `assert(str == NULL);`, use `if (str == NULL) return -1;`.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I've thought that assert() is something like the if(). When I try to use your code I'm getting an error for this part: *str[i] = malloc(sizeof *str[i] * 100);* 
Operand of * must be an pointer. That's what it says but I've already declared it as a pointer *char *str = (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));*

Comment: @Dragan Zrilic Then use `char **str= malloc(sizeof *str * n);` **instead** of `str[i] = malloc(sizeof *str[i] * 100);`.